# Missing property in path, json schema karate

Tags: karate

I'm trying to validate a json response with Karate json schema validation. I've already used it many times in many ways, and in this simple example I can't undestand what's wrong. Here is the response I get:

```
 * def response =
 """
[{
 "id" : "1111",
 "surname" : "Debby",
 "name" : "Johns",
 "status" : "MARRIED",
 "rooms" : [{
    "number" : "2",
    "state" : "clean",
    "owner" : {
       "name" : "Mrs Johns",
       "address" : "New York",
       "birth_date" : 1555493518,
       "birth_place" : "Jersey",
       "phone_number" : "078******1"
     },
 "keys" : [{
     "id" : "aaa",
     "color" : "blue"
 }]
}],
"creation_date" : 1555493458,
"left" : false
}]
 """
```

And here is the schema:

```
* def ownerSchema =
"""
  {
      name: '#string',
      address: '##string',
      birth_date: '##number',
      birth_place: '##string',
      phone_number: '##string'
   }
"""

* def keySchema =
"""
{
  id: '#string',
  color: '#string'
}
"""

* def roomSchema =
"""
  {
    number: '#string',
    state: '#string',
    owner: "#('##(ownerSchema)')",
    keys: '##[] keySchema'
  }
"""

* def clientSchema =
"""
  {
    id: '#string',
    surname: '##string',
    name: '#string',
    status: '#string',
    creation_date: '#number',
    left: '#boolean',
    rooms: '#[] roomSchema'
  }
"""
```

When I try to validate it:
    * match each response == clientSchema

The error is: Missing property in path $[0]['rooms']
It makes me crazy, I can't find out.

Comment: I copied exactly your code, and it works for me. Which version are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to write it, I use 0.6.1. I've changed it to 0.9.2 and it works

Comment: I didn't updated karate before because there is another problem, but I will ask in another post if I don't find a response. Thanks @Adrien

Comment: @nirind : You can answer your own question so that the solution is more obvious. [Self answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are encouraged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in 0.9.2 onwards.